# Add control inside jQuery autocomplete and refresh list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I am displaying ranking information (How many times the list item got selected) for each item in jQuery auto complete result. Now I want to add a control inside the autocomplete for each item and clicking on it should decrement the ranking and also should refresh the autocomplete list.

CODE :

```
if (item.Value != null && item.Value != "" && item.Value != "0") {
                    return $("<li></li>")
                        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                        .append("<a style='color:Blue;'>" + item.label + "<span id='ancClearRanking' style='float:right;z-index:1000;' class='clearranking'>X</span><span id='spn`enter code here`Ranking' style='color:Green;font-size:10px;float:right;'>(" + item.Value + ")</span>" + "</a>")
                             .appendTo(ul);
                }
```

Here item.Value is the ranking information. I wrote the below function to bind the clear ranking click event(`<span id='ancClearRanking' style='float:right;z-index:1000;' class='clearranking'>X</span>`).

CODE :

```
 $(document).delegate("ul .clearranking", "click", function (e) {
                    var isConfirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
                    if (isConfirmed) {
                        $(inputcontrol).autocomplete("search");
                    }
                });
```

I am facing 2 issues.

1) While clicking on the clear ranking, select function is called first. I wanted to restrict that.

2) Firing $(inputcontrol).autocomplete("search") is not triggering.

Could you please help.

Comment: Please provide the rest of code that is required to reproduce this. read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have created a mock case http://jsfiddle.net/L25mwnv3/1/